# SearchView not expanding

Tags: android, search, searchview

For setting up the SearchView Interface:

1.My Menu item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search Members"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

2.Activity's Menu Inflater:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);

    return true;
}
```

3.And adding meta-data to Activity(Manifest):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

But the SearchView icon doesn't expand.
Can Someone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

**1. menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

**2. In Activity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
    }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**3. Add this in manifest**

```
<meta-data 
      android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
      android:value="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity" /> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

**4. create file searchable xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Yes,This does the work.But can you please tell me what was the problem in my code?

Comment: app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"